# Symlinking unicorn_init.sh into /etc/init.d doesn't show with chkconfig --list

Tags: sinatra, server, unicorn, centos6

I'm symlinking my config/unicorn_init.sh to /etc/init.d/unicorn_project with:

```
sudo ln -nfs config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_<project>
```

Afterwards, when I run `chkconfig --list` my unicorn_ script doesn't show. I'm adding my unicorn script to load my application on server load.

Obviously, this is not allowing me to add my script with:

```
chkconfig unicorn_<project> on
```

Any help / advice would be awesome :).

**Edit:**

Also, when I'm in /etc/init.d/ and run:

```
sudo service unicorn_project start
```

It says: "unrecognized service"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. There were two things wrong with what I was doing:

1) You have to make sure your unicorn script can play nice with chkconfig by adding the below code below `#!/bin/bash`. Props to [digitalocean's blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-and-unicorn-boot-question-run-on-start-up) for the help.

```
# chkconfig:   2345 95 20
# description: Controls Unicorn sinatra server
# processname: unicorn
```

2) I was attempting to symlink the config/unicorn_init.sh file when I was already in the project directory which was creating a dangling symlink (pink colored symlink ~> should be teal) by using a relative path. To fix this, I removed the dangling symlink and provided the absolute path to the unicorn_init.sh file.

To debug this I used `ll` in the /etc/init.d/ directory to see r,w,x permissions and file types, was running `chkconfig --list` to see a list of services in /etc/init.d/ and also was trying to run the dangling symlink in my /etc/init.d directory with `sudo service unicorn_<project> restart`

Hope this helps someone.